# What is a suicide plasmid?

Tags: cloning, plasmids, definitions

What is a suicide plasmid?

Example: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2737453/ mentions a "suicide vector". See also http://www.sci.sdsu.edu/~smaloy/MicrobialGenetics/topics/plasmids/allele-exchange.html which also mentions them.

Comment: While the answer to this is quite straightforward (see mine below), finding a source is less so. I will accept an answer which provides an appropriate reference for the definition.

Comment: Check out [this page](http://www.sci.sdsu.edu/~smaloy/MicrobialGenetics/topics/plasmids/allele-exchange.html) - it has a long discussion of suicide vectors, and from the note at the bottom it was adapted from a published source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As can be inferred from the Shanks et al. paper linked in the question: In molecular biology, "suicide plasmid" is a term that refers to a plasmid which is **replication incompetent**.*

Plasmids normally bear a sequence called "origin of replication" `Ori` which marks the plasmid for replication by the host cell. Plasmids that lack this `Ori` will not be replicated during cell division, and will become diluted away and/or degraded after a few generations. Hence the name: The plasmid will "commit suicide" by promptly becoming eliminated from the population of DNA molecules inside each cell.

Note that because not all `Ori`s are universal, the same exact plasmid may be a normal vector in one species (eg. E. coli) and a suicide vector in another species (eg. P. aeruginosa) - which is logical: If a vector can't replicate in any species at all, how do you produce this vector in the first place? (there are ways, but they are laborious)

---

*: I am unable to find an authoritative source for this definition. The other two paragraphs are common knowledge.